# Why is Javascript called Javascript, if it has nothing to do with Java?

Tags: java, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is JavaScript called JavaScript, if it has nothing to do with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018731/why-is-javascript-called-javascript-if-it-has-nothing-to-do-with-java)

Why Javascript is called Javascript (there is no relation between Java and Javascript) why its not called HTMLScript or XMLScript. Any historical reason for this?