# Can't get JavaScript loop to work when padded with zeroes

Tags: javascript

Trying to write some html to a div in 001, 002, 003 style format but I can't get it to work.

Here's the code:

```
function loadpics(x, url) {
  var txt, i;
  txt = "";
  for(i = 1; i < x; i++) {
    txt = txt + String.format("%03d", i) + "<br/>";
  }
  document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

When I hopefully get it to work, I intend to load some images to the div like so:

```
function loadpics(x, url) {
  var txt, i;
  txt = "";
  for(i = 1; i < x; i++) {
    txt = txt + "<img src=\"" + url + "/t/" + String.format("%03d", i) + ".jpg\"></img><br/>";
  }
  document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

Can't get the string formatting to work though. Not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong.

If anyone can put me straight it would be most appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: What's String.format? JavaScript is **not** Java.

Comment: Are you trying to add padding to numbers?

Comment: Thanks for replying, got it sorted very quickly thank you =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `pad()` instead of `String.format()`.

```js
function pad(number, length) {
  var str = '' + number;
  while (str.length < length) {
    str = '0' + str;
  }
  return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your page

```
function pad(number, length) {
  var str = '' + number;
  while (str.length < length) {
    str = '0' + str;
  }
  return str;
}
```

And replace `txt=txt...` with this

```
txt +=  "<img src='" + url + "/t/" + pad(i,3) + ".jpg'></img><br/>";
```

Also have a look at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018731/why-is-javascript-called-javascript-since-it-has-nothing-to-do-with-java)