# disqus comment count update

Tags: javascript, disqus

I am trying to get the comment count from disqus. Now To count comments, I just use javascript provided by Disqus like this

```
 function () {
            var s = document.createElement('script');
            s.async = true;
            s.type = 'text/javascript';
            s.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/count.js';
            (document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0]).appendChild(s);
        }()
```

Btw, I look into them which are not updated right now. 
So I want to solve this problem how to update the number of comments in real-time. 
Do you have any idea for this? 
Please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: _"Java is to Javascript what Car is to Carpet"_. I like that quote. And it's accurate :p

Comment: Do you happen to remember where you heard that from?

Comment: @supersam654 Yes, it was a comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2018731/645270). Remember to use the `@` so I get a notification

Answer (score 0):

To load disqus comments count dynamically add the following code to your template:

```
DISQUSWIDGETS.getCount({reset: true});
```

One common use case of this function is to update elements on the page that were not available via the initial load of count.js.